# What is the word for when one refers to another's action to lessen the severity of their own?

Tags: terminology

Suppose Person A is accused of an act, which in this case is a hate crime. Person A then points to the actions of Person B, who has committed similar but a more severe form of that action.

This is used by Person A to lessen the severity of their action by referring to Person B.

Ex. Person A has referred to an African American using a derogatory, racist term. When accused as a racist, person A states "Well, Person B has been using this all the time and no one says anything to him/her!"

Comment: Isn’t that some combination of “finger-pointing, blame-shifting and rationalization”

Comment: Can't think of a single word, but the "They're just as bad" argument is a common one. e.g. when caught for a minor offence, some people will complain "why aren't you catching the real bad guys like murderers, thieves, etc.".

Comment: My first thought was "mitigation", though there are a few others that might fit: "evasion" and "justification" are the main ones, though the general idea is of making an excuse or shifting blame/attention.

Answer (score 2):

If the defendant refers  to another's behaviour (but more especially to legal decisions on that behaviour), you could say they are **justifying theirs by referring to a precedent.**

Precedent has a [formal legal definition](https://www.lawteacher.net/free-law-essays/judicial-law/judicial-precedent-is-source-of-law.php) too.

Comment: I don't think this bears any relevance to the question. You rely on a precedent to claim that what you did is not against the law. That is not what the accused claims here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've removed the legal definition which admittedly formed too large a proportion of the first answer. I did consider removing the whole answer as I think the word *precedent* in a general non-legal usage may still be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

> **whataboutery** 
>   mass noun.
>   British
>   The technique or practice of responding to an accusation or difficult question by making a counter-accusation or raising a different issue.
>   *‘all too often, well-intentioned debate descends into whataboutery’*
>   Also called whataboutism
>   Origin
>   1970s: from the way in which counter-accusations may take the form of questions introduced by ‘What about —?’.
>   — [O-D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whataboutery)

Answer (score 1):

A deleted post here [edit: it's back, by k1eran], mentioned **whataboutism**. This, or more generally the *tu quoque*, is probably the closest of the generally known logical fallacies (collated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies)). However, those are where the person specifically refers to her opponent's *own* hypocrisy, not that of a third party.

I would perhaps call this an *appeal to inconsistent application of the law*, or just an *appeal to inconsistency*. The person is claiming that the fact that someone else wasn't censured for the same racism justifies his own act. In fact, the reaction of others in a separate incident has no bearing on this one.

Comment: Here's a link for [tu quoque](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/tu-quoque) for a site I like about fallacies in general.

Answer (score 0):

In legal terms, such claim is against *discriminatory enforcement* of the law, and can be grounds for acquittal.

> The biased use of enforcement discretion, such as that based on racial
>   prejudice or corruption, is usually considered a legal abuse and a
>   threat to the rule of law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_enforcement

Comment: Ah, yet another [malicious downvote](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10241/194459).

Answer (score 0):

I think that, as previously suggested, *whataboutism* or *tu quoque* is the proper name, but if you're looking for something a little more informal to describe what's happening, perhaps ***deflection*** is what you're looking for?

> ***[deflect](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deflect)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *[with object, and usually with adverbial of direction]* Cause (something) to change direction; turn aside from a straight course.
>    *‘the bullet was deflected harmlessly into the ceiling’*
>    *[figurative] **‘he attempted to deflect attention away from his private life’***

(Emphasis mine.)